C++ Returning a lambda's return value
Please help, as there are only so many ways to search "return a lambda return value" before you lose your mind!
int someFunction(){
    return [](int a){ return a; };
}

I want to return the value, not the lambda.

What value do you want to pass as a?  If you're creating and calling the lambda all within one function why are you involving a lambda at all?

I'm using a lambda within a lambda callback function, but really pared it down to the minimum to post here as per the instructions on the site.

If this isn't the problem you will have to come up with a better / more representative example code. The problem is now there is an upvoted answer based on the previous code. Usually we don't like changing the topic after it's answered.

"there are only so many ways to search 'return a lambda return value'" -- I tweaked this a bit and searched for [c++] returning lambda "return value" and came up with What is the significance of returning the return value of a lambda expression from a function, which starts with code that does what you want to do, and Returning value from lambda in the same line with declaration, which differs only in that it assigns the return value to a variable instead of returning it. Same idea, though.

To clarify: I reported what I searched for as a demonstration of what could be done. It should not be taken as admonishment of what should have been done. (After all, it was not the first search I tried for this.)

Lambda is (in a great simplification) just a function. You need to call it to have its body executed. Since this lambda requires one argument, you can call it for example with (13), so
return [](int a){ return a; }(13);
// or a version with easier syntax
auto lambda = [](int a){ return a; };
return lambda(13);

Although at this point there is no point in using lambda and you should just
return 13;

